# How to pass result of one sp to other sp and taking back that calculated result to again to first sp?

Tags: sql, sql-server

These are sample tables

```
UserDetails : id,UserName,IsShow
Brand       : id,BrandName
Product     : id,ProductName
BrandProduct:id,brandid,productid,price
```

If Isshow is false, show entire price else hide second -fourth digit.(Price is 5 digits)

Sp 1:

```
create procedure Sp_Details
@brandid int,
@productid int,
@IsShow bit
as
begin
        select B.Brandname,P.Producetname,Bp.Price
        from BrandProduct Bp
        inner join B
        on Bp.brandid = B.id
        inner join P
        on Bp.productid = P.id
        where brandid = @brandid
        and productid = @productid 
// If Isshow is true show this as result,else pass this result to one sp(generic sp) which take that result and do following (replace ) and give result to this sp.

REPLACE(Price, (SUBSTRING(Price,2, 3*@Isshow)), 'xxx')
    end
```

How to do that?How to pass this result to another sp,get calculated result back to this sp?.There are so many place/pages on which this has to work,that's why created generic sp.Many user can interract with same sp simultaneously.One user data should not mix with other.

Comment: Create a Generic function to replace the price with (xxx) instead of SP. So that you can call that function inside the SP 1. Refer the msdn link for creating function https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Note, this is not OOP language, it behaves different. Encapsulation of such tiny things may degrade performance drastically. If you need to hide `price` from some groups of users then you'd better write different SPs/views and grant specific permissions to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If generic stored procedures is required then you can use temp table to share data between stored procedures. Inner stored procedure will see temp table created in outer stored prcoedure. Example:

```
create procedure Sp_Details
@brandid int,
@productid int,
@IsShow bit
as
begin
    select SomeColumns
    into #tableForMechanism   
    from SomeData

    if @IsShow = 0 then
    begin
       exec innerDetailsProcedure
    end              

    select SomeColumns from #tableForMechanism   
end
go

create procedure innerDetailsProcedure
begin
    if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tableForMechanism') is NULL    
    begin 
        raiserror('Table for mechanism is not created', 16, 1);
        return -1;
    end;

    INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE #tableForMechanism   
end
go
```

If data is always returned then parameter @IsShow should be renamed to express its real purpouse like @doXYZModification

Check also this link: How to Share Data between Stored Procedures http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html

Comment: Temp table is created based on user.I can't get same temp table created by that user.

Comment: Scope of the Local Temporary Table is the session in which it is created and they are dropped automatically once the session ends so users should be able to call this main procedure many times and no data will be shared between calls.

Comment: Hi Tomasz,thanks for reply.I want to ask u one question.I am accessing page/sp,one temp table is created for me.Like this 'tableForMechanism_16565765765'.Session id get appened at the end of tablename.Will this search for my table,it will searchgeneric one. if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tableForMechanism') is NULL

Answer (score 1):

You can do everything in a single stored procedure, using a simple `case` expression:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Stp_Details -- NOTE THE CHANGE OF THE NAME!
    @brandid int,
    @productid int,
    @IsShow bit
AS
BEGIN
        SELECT B.Brandname,
               P.Producetname,
               CASE WHEN @IsShow = 1 THEN 
                   Bp.Price
               ELSE
                   RIGHT(Price ,2) + 'xxx'
               END AS Price
        FROM BrandProduct Bp
        INNER JOIN B
            ON Bp.brandid = B.id
        INNER JOIN P
            ON Bp.productid = P.id
        WHERE brandid = @brandid
        AND productid = @productid 
END
```

A couple of notes:

1. Do not use the `sp_` prefix for stored procedures. This prefix is reserved by Microsoft for system procedures so you might get name collisions.
2. Proper casing and indentation makes for a much readable code.
3. Instead of your cumbersome `REPLACE(Price, (SUBSTRING(Price,2, 3*@Isshow)), 'xxx')` I've simply used `RIGHT` and a simple string concatenation.